# SyntaxError in yield statement

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy to extract data. Here's a code snippet -

```
def parse(self, response): 

   lis = response.css('li.col-xs-6')

        for item in lis:  

            yield {
                'title' : item.xpath('.//h3/a/@title').getall(),
                'price' : item.xpath('.//div/p/text()').get(),
                'listing-link' : 'http://books.toscrape.com/',item.xpath('.//h3/a/@href').getall()
                }


        
        next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page is not None: 
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback= self.parse)
```

Here's the error that I get when I run my scraper -

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 916, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 846, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/arif/scrapy_practice/quotes/quotes/spiders/booksquotes.py", line 40
    }
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Before I added the block for following the pagination, it seemed to work well an no SyntaxError was raised. The error started occuring after I added this block -

```
next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page is not None: 
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback= self.parse)
```

Comment: There's a comma in the value for `listing-link` that's causing the exception

Comment: If the intention is that the value for `listing-link` should be a tuple, then put it explicitly in parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma in 'listing-link' is the problem.

You can use f-string in such cases.

```
# value is array in here
value = item.xpath(".//h3/a/@href").getall()

# convert to string first
value = ''.join(item.xpath(".//h3/a/@href").getall())

# or you could use indexing depending on your requirement
value = value[0]

# and then in yield

'listing-link' : f'http://books.toscrape.com/{value}'
```

I don't think `getAll()` is what you need while yielding. It returns an array. I think you need an string and not an array. Be careful about that too.